# Confused over encoding/locale in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, encoding, localization

I am a little confused over the difference between encoding and locale as it pertains to the postgresql database.

When initializing the database, you can specify both an encoding and a locale.  Correct me if I am wrong but I assume the encoding defines what the database is actually stored as on the computer.

So if I specify `UTF8`, all the characters in the `UTF8` character set would be valid characters.  If I specified `WIN1252`, all those characters would be valid characters.  What I dont get is where the locale comes into play.  If I specify my encoding as `UTF8` and then specify my locale as `English_United States.1252`, what does that exactly mean?

I think the `WIN1252` character set is a subset of `UTF8` so is the locale just specifying the subset of characters to be used from the `UTF8` character set?

From what I have read is that UTF8 can be used with ANY locale so what is the point in specifying different encodings if UTF8 is so ubiquitous and the locale is really the one specifying the specific character set to be used?

Also, on Linux, the locale can be specified like so: `en_us.utf8`.  So the database encoding is specified in the locale?  If the encoding is specified in the locale, why even have a `-encoding` flag when initializing the database?

Comment: encoding is how characters are physically stored (one byte, two bytes, three bytes, ...), the locale determines how characters are sorted and compared (e.g. is `Häh` sorted before or after `Hah`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**`encoding`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/multibyte.html) defines the very basic rules how characters are represented in binary format (like [@a_horse explains in his comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47663/confused-over-encoding-locale-in-postgresql#comment84769_47663)). It should be mentioned that the server encoding has to match the client encoding for successful communication. Postgres can translate if necessary, there is a dedicated setting [`client_encoding`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CLIENT-ENCODING) for this.

The [**`locale`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/locale.html) is a superset of settings, which can be split up for PostgreSQL into

> ```
> LC_COLLATE
> LC_CTYPE
> LC_MESSAGES
> LC_MONETARY
> LC_NUMERIC
> LC_TIME
> ```

The settings of particular interest for you are `LC_COLLATE` (defines how strings are sorted) and `LC_TYPE` (defines the type of characters).
In older versions, these two settings could not be changed after a database had been initialized. Since Postgres 9.1 you can at least [override the collation setting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/collation.html) when needed.

Comment: Thanks! that helped a lot.  So just to make it clear, the LC_CTYPE has to be a subset of the characters represented in the encoding? So the LC_CTYPE tells you which characters in the encoding your allowed to use and which ones you cannot use?